# Sort NSDates inside NSDictionary inside NSArray?

Tags: ios, sorting, nsdate, nsdictionary

Currently in my app I have a NSArray that I load from NSUserDefaults. Each object in the NSArray is a NSDictionary that has about 5 different keys. I am re-order the **NSDictionarys** themselves based upon the NSDates inside of them. I do not want to sort the NSDates alone.

I have tried to do this with this code:

```
NSComparator sortByDate = ^(id dict1, id dict2) {
        NSDate* n1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Date"];
        NSDate* n2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"Date"];
        return (NSComparisonResult)[n1 compare:n2];
    };
    [self.cellArray sortUsingComparator:sortByDate];
```

Although nothing happens even though the code gets executed. I am confused though about how to re-order the NSDictionarys based upon something inside of it.

Can anyone offer any insight on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an NSLog output before and after the sort?

Comment: @RyanPoolos I am refreshing the UITableView after I do this so I would definitely see any changes made anyway. Is there something wrong with my code that is not making this work?

Comment: Also perhaps try NSLoging your n1, and n2 and make sure they're valid date objects getting pulled properly.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Thought you don't need (NSComparisonResult)

Comment: Hmm that was odd, it somehow was fixed although it seems to be backwards. It puts the old dates first and new dates last, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes check my answer in a sec I'll edit it to let you control backwards or forwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try sorting it inline but I doubt that would have any major effect. But I can say i never abstract out my blocks. I would definitely try NSLogging too to make sure you're getting valid NSDates.

```
    [cells sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate *n1 = [obj1 objectForKey:@"Date"];
        NSDate *n2 = [obj2 objectForKey:@"Date"];

        if (n1 > n2) {
            return NSOrderedAscending;
        } else (n1 < n2) {
            return NSOrderedDescending;
        } else {
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }

    }];
```

Comment: just reverse your operators or your returns to get the order you desire :)

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. However, I am confused with the newest dates being first ordering. That is the only ordering I want. I am a bit confused on why you are using if and else's. Isn't there some way to edit this line to do what I want? return (NSComparisonResult)[n1 compare:n2];

Comment: The if statements do the work. If n1 is greater than n2 it is returned with n1 before n2. otherwise its returned n2 before n1. NSDates are just int representing the seconds since 1970. So simple greater than less than operators will determine which is older.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will accept the answer but there seems to be a deeper problem for me, not sure if you will help me :P but it seems that my NSArray gets sorted properly and I call reloadData on my UITableView however none of my cells get re-ordered the what the NSArray is ordered to. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd need to see some more code. Let me see your tableview datasource code. And it may be worth starting a new question for it to attract some more answers if i can't figure it out.

Comment: Check out my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675792/reloaddata-not-working-for-uitableview-datasource  Also don't take this the wrong way but I decided to use some different code since it is less lines and works the same :)

Comment: No biggy, I forgot about descriptors. I've been in love with blocks lately haha. But it probably the better way for your case.