# reloadData not working for UITableView dataSource?

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, nsdictionary

Currently I have a NSMutableArray that loads from NSUserDefaults in my app and feeds the data to my UITableView. The NSMutableArray consists of NSDictionarys which consist of 5 or 6 keys each.

Then in the view where the UITableView is, I have a UISegmentedControl where the user can then sort the UITableView based upon Date or some other things.

So when they click the date segment, I execute this code:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Date" ascending:NO];
[self.cellArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor]];
```

The sorting itself works as I can see self.cellArray being sorted through NSLogs. Although when I call my tableview to reloadData, none of the NSDictionarys actually re-sort in the tableview itself. So programmatically they are being sorted but not in the UI which is extremely odd.

If use this for statement right after the code I posted above:

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.cellArray) {
            NSLog(@"DateKey: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Date"]);
}
```

This is what my NSLogs look like if I do ascending:YES :

```
2012-05-20 13:48:21.008 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-13 18:19:22 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.009 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-13 18:19:29 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.009 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-15 01:54:13 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.010 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-15 04:01:15 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.011 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:08:20 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.012 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:13:59 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.012 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:32:29 +0000
2012-05-20 13:48:21.013 App[71308:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:32:38 +0000
```

If I do ascending:NO this is what my NSLogs look like:

```
2012-05-20 13:56:25.956 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:32:38 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.960 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:32:29 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.961 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:13:59 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.961 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-16 04:08:20 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.962 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-15 04:01:15 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.962 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-15 01:54:13 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.963 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-13 18:19:29 +0000
2012-05-20 13:56:25.964 App[71468:707] DateKey: 2012-05-13 18:19:22 +0000
```

So as you can see, the sorting indeed works properly but once I do reloadData after that code, my UITableView does not re-order the cells based upon the Date key.

My tableview is in fact connected in IB and is not nil. I do have a setter and getter for it to if that matters.

Does anyone have any idea why this happening? Or do you need more context/code?

Thanks!

Comment: Show us `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. i.e. is it actually reading from `cellArray`?

Comment: I added my cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I'm confused then. That looks fine. Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` definitely being called after `reloadData`?

Comment: Yes it is. I NSLogged it and it shows the cellForRowAtIndexPath getting called when I call reloadData. I even added the willDisplayCell delegate method and NSLogged that too and that gets called also. So this is really odd! One other thing I would like to mention is that the cellForRowAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell both get called while I am scrolling my UITableView also, is this normal behavior for iOS 5?

Comment: Yes it's normal whilst you're scrolling - it's getting the cells that are about to appear on screen. Still no idea why this isn't working for you. Can you perhaps post the project somewhere for download?

Comment: Sorry no I cannot since it is part of a bigger project which cannot be shared at all. Any other possible remedies?

Comment: Are you sure you're not setting `cellArray` back to the original array later on or something?

Comment: Aha! That was it! In my segmented control update method I was not setting my cellArray to NSUserDefaults so in my numberOfRowsInSection that was where I was updating the array with what was in NSUserDefaults so that what was preventing it form working! If you post that comment as an answer, I will accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to put your logging statement ...

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in self.cellArray)
    NSLog(@"DateKey: %@", [dict objectForKey:@"Date"]);
```

in, right after you invoke `sortUsingDescriptors` as well in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. I'd also put a NSLog statement right where cellArray is getting initialized (to make sure that you're not accidentally invoking that again ... easy to do if your routines get complicated).

I have to believe that the order in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not reflect the order you got immediately after your sort. Assuming this is the case, either cellArray is getting reset somewhere (i.e. where do you populate it? in viewDidLoad or somewhere else?), or your sortUsingDescriptors is not getting invoked like you think it is.

Just start putting break points and/or debugging messages in your various routines. It's got to be something simple. I just did a test of reloading where I resort as I reload, and the sort orders are being preserved. So it's got to be something simple.