# What's going on behind the scenes in a NSComparator block?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've looked at some questions such as [Sort NSDates inside NSDictionary inside NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668392/sort-nsdates-inside-nsdictionary-inside-nsarray) that explain how to sort an array of dictionaries. But I haven't found an explanation of how the NSComparator block actually works, and I'm really curious.

Example code (from above-linked Q):

```
NSComparator sortByDate = ^(id dict1, id dict2) {
    NSDate* n1 = [dict1 objectForKey:@"Date"];
    NSDate* n2 = [dict2 objectForKey:@"Date"];
    return [n1 compare:n2];
};

[self.cellArray sortUsingComparator:sortByDate];
```

Where do the block's two inputs come from? How does the iteration that must be required to sort a collection come into play? Etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you were writing the method to do this. You would sort the array using any of the efficient algorithms for sorting (which one doesn't matter, it's a well studied problem in computer science).

At the heart of this sorting method, you would be comparing two items to see which one should be ordered higher than the other. But as you are writing a generic sorting method, you don't know how the actual objects are to be sorted. So you would leave the actual comparison method to the person who is actually wants to use your method, and they would provide that method in a block. So, you would write your method something like this.

```
- (NSArray *)mySortMethodUsingBlock:(NSComparator(^)(id obj1, id obj2))comparator {
    // Keep repeating these steps til the array is sorted:
    // Some methods to walk the array get two elements to examine
    // Pass these two objects to the block that the user has provided and get their order
    NSComparator result = comparator (anObj, anotherObj);
    // Use the result to determine how the objects are positioned

    // Return the sorted array.
}
```

So. When you are creating the comparator block - you are just telling the method how to compare two objects. The method can then take care of using this information to sort the array in an efficient manner.

Comment: Ah, I see, the sortUsingComparator method does all the "behind the scenes" work, and the comparator just supplies exactly what its name implies. Makes sense. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of the array's sort method probably uses a binary sort or some other efficient sort algorithm that needs to repeatedly compare two objects in the array. Each time it needs to do the comparison it calls the block passing in whatever two objects it needs to evaluate. The result of the block tells the algorithm how the two objects compare to each other.